# Translating excel formula into power query language

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Could someone please assist with helping me create a formula using Power Query that performs the same as the following Excel formula?

```
=iferror(iferror(if(value(left([Qualifications],1))>0,right([Qualifications],len([Qualifications])-7),""),left([Qualifications],find("/",[Qualifications])-4)),[Qualifications])
```

Essentially I am trying to strip out expiration dates from a column which contains the qualification title and expiration date (if any) at the end of the title, ideally to just show the qualification title. As some of the qualifications use () in the title, I need to search for the presence of / in the title and remove characters around these.

[image: Qualifications column image]

As I'm new to using Power Query, it's proving a little time consuming trying to learn and understand the different language to Excel!

EDIT - This is the Token Eof error I receive when pasting the provided code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWBwL.png)

EDIT 2 - This is the error that is showing in multiple rows, including the row with the date at the end

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA4Vw.png)

Comment: You don't show what you want for output, but if your output would be all those lines with any dates removed, then I'd probably just use a regular expression to replace the date with nothing

Answer (score 1):

A powerquery solution .. Assuming you want to remove **(##/##/####)** then

Paste below into a blank query in home ... advanced editor ... name it **RegExReplace** and then file .. close and load

```
/*
https://www.mathscinotes.com/2020/02/power-query-regular-expression-hack/
Mark Biegert
Modified version of regex routine documented by Imke Feldman at
https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/04/25/regex-in-power-bi-and-power-query-in-excel-with-java-script/
Input Parameter:
x : String to be searched
y : Search regex
z : Replacement regex
*/
(x,y,z)=>
let Source = Web.Page(
"<script>var x="&"'"&x&"'"&";var z="&"'"&z&
"'"&";var y=new RegExp('"&y&"','g');
var b=x.replace(y,z);document.write(b);</script>")
[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}
in Source
```

Then in your data to clean, Add column .. custom column .. with formula

```
= RegExReplace([YourColumnName],"\\(\\d{2}\/\\d{2}\/\\d{4}\\)","")
```

Comment: When I paste the formula into advanced editor, I receive a "Expression.SyntaxError: Token Eof expected" error - could you please let me know how I would fix this?

Comment: My code works as listed. Edit your question to post a copy of your code for us to look at. Did you use the name of your column instead of YourColumnName? Did you name the function RegExReplace and use that same spelling and capitalization when you referred to it in your custom column formula?

Comment: Please see the edit I have included regarding the Token Eof error - this is occurring when pasting the provided code, and I am not able to progress to the second step of creating the custom column. Could you please assist?

Comment: Odd.  What happens if you remove all text before (x

Comment: The text above is the API collection of data and some other data cleaning I have completed. Without this, I would assume the code you have provided won't have any data to reference? Prior to adding the code provided, there are no errors etc. Is there a way to include the code you have provided and still keep the API data?

Comment: I am confused. Are you entering my function code in its own query as you should be, or tacking it on to existing code.  It needs to be standalone and I can’t think of a reason not to as it would not impact anything else.  Then the add column command can be added anywhere

Comment: Perhaps the instructions should have been worded differently.  I changed it to say "Paste below into a blank query in home ... advanced editor"

Comment: I've now entered the function code in its own query, which isn't showing up any errors. Even after closing and loading, I'm now receiving an error when adding the custom column 'Expression.Error: The name 'RegExReplace' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly'? I'm pretty sure I've spelt it correctly and have adjusted [YourColumnName] to be the column I want to clean

Comment: You apparently didn’t name the new function code with the same name as you are using to call it

Comment: I've now rectified this error. There is now an error showing in multiple lines which I have included in the edit above. The function also failed to extract the date from the QBCC Licence line - how can this be rectified?

Comment: Sorry.  I’m giving up here